# Import table from url with r - but numeric columns are characters

Tags: r, url, numeric, rvest, xml2

I have following code:

```
url <- "https://lebensmittel-naehrstoffe.de/calciumhaltige-lebensmittel/"
page <- read_html(url) #Creates an html document from URL
Ca <- html_table(page, fill = TRUE, dec = ",") #Parses tables into data frames
Ca <- data.frame(Ca)
```

But my last column of my data.frame Ca[,4] consists of values containing "." and "," - hence it is a german talbe the dec is",", but in R it is always a character. I tried already with gsub and as.numeric, but it always failed. Pleasse note: I already put dec=","

Could someone help me? If possible it should be a solution to run it on a lot of data.frames (or html imports or what ever) because I have many such tables...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `readr::parse_number` :

```
Ca <- html_table(page, fill = TRUE, dec = ",")[[1]]
Ca$`Calciumgehalt in mg` <- readr::parse_number(Ca$`Calciumgehalt in mg`, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."))
str(Ca)

# 'data.frame': 82 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ Lebensmittel       : chr  "Basilikum, getrocknet" "Majoran, getrocknet" "Thymian, getrocknet" "Selleriesamen" ...
# $ Kategorie          : chr  "Gewürze" "Gewürze" "Gewürze" "Gewürze" ...
# $ Mengenangabe       : chr  "je 100 Gramm" "je 100 Gramm" "je 100 Gramm" "je 100 Gramm" ...
# $ Calciumgehalt.in.mg: num  2240 1990 1890 1767 1597 ...
```

Comment: Since you have a data.frame with numbers formatted accoring to German standards, "parse_number" won't parse them properly (mixing-up decimal and grouping marks). Therefore, you have to add the option "locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = ".")" in the "parse_number" function.

Comment: Friends! You're awesome. Thank you very much! it works! I would never ever find this solution... :)